# How to automatically redirect the youtube home page button to "/feed/subscriptions/u" with Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to create an extension that will automatically redirect the youtube home page button to "/feed/subscriptions/u" instead of the usually homepage.

I have only two files manifest.json and background.js

manifest contains this

```
{
  "name": "Youtube Home Redirector",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Redirects Youtube Home Page automatically to subscriptions",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

and my background.js contains

```
$('a[title*="Youtube home"]').attr('href', function(i,href) {
    return href.replace('/', '/feed/subscriptions/u');
});
```

I know this doesn't work.... I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction of how to do this.

Comment: Side note: please change title to be meaningful - no need to copy tag value into title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your code has few problems*

a) You are in background page not in tab you are browsing

b) $.attr() is not recognized by background page.

c) You do not have permissions on tab(s) you are updating.

The following sample can achieve your functionality.

### References:

a) [Manifest Files](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html) and [Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)

b) [tabs.query()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) *: For fetching all tab(s) before installation*

c) [tabs.onUpdated.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) *: For fetching new tab(s) after installation*

d) [chrome.tabs.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-update) *: For changing all tab(s) URL.*

## Demonstration

#### manifest.json

Ensure all permissions are avialable for manifest

```
{
    "name": "URL Change",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This demonstrates how chrome extension Changes URL",
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    },

    "permissions": ["tabs","http://www.youtube.com/*"]
}
```

#### background.js

This ensures all existing tabs and all newly created tab(s) after installation with http://www.youtube.com/ URL are updated to http://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions/u

```
//Take tabId as input and change its URL
var changeURL = function (tabId) {
    //Update its URL
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {
        "url": "http://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions/u"
    }, function (tab) {
        //Notification for success
        console.log("Tab Updated");
    });

}

//Query  All tabs with URL's http://www.youtube.com/ when extension is installed for first time
chrome.tabs.query({
    "url": "http://www.youtube.com/"
}, function (tabs) {
    //For every tab change URL by Passing Id
    for (tab in tabs) {
        changeURL(tabs[tab].id);
    }
});

//When ever a new tab is created this changes URL
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, info, tab) {
    //Fetch a tab where URL is http://www.youtube.com/ and is not loaded yet
    if (info.status == "loading" && info.url == "http://www.youtube.com/") {
        //Change URL by passing Id of tab
        changeURL(tabId);
    }
});
```

### Output:

[image]

Let me know if you need more information.